# Register Azure App in Azure Partner Center via a cmdlet or rest api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, az, microsoft-partnercenter-java

I currently have to access the Azure Partner Portal (https://partnercenter.microsoft.com) in order to register an app registration from Azure. I'd like to automate this via a powershell script but it appears no cmdlet exist to perform this function. To clarify, a module of cmdlets exist for Partner Center functions ([link](https://github.com/microsoft/partner-center-powershell/) here) but none of these will register an app registration. Has anyone ran into this issue and how did you handle it outside of performing it manually in the partner center portal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Currently, there is no command support to register Partner Center App. It's necessary to register the app through the Partner Center Portal.

You can submit the request into GitHub here so that the developer team can review the request:

microsoft/Partner-Center-PowerShell

You can also submit a request in [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/).